# Toplink to Eclipselink migration support

Tags: orm, migration, eclipselink, toplink

Could someone please let us know if there is any contact of the eclipse community who can provide us with support for a problem we are facing during migration of Toplink to Eclipselink (native api, non-JPA)?

We are ready to explore paid options if any.
Please contact at rohanrele@hotmail.com

Comment: Just sent you an email

Comment: I'd suggest you contact Oracle who have support for both TopLink and EclipseLink as a part of their servers.

Comment: @Chris could you please provide us such a contact if you know?